# Accessing multiple pixels per read/write in openCV using 64bit operations

Tags: image, opencv, memory, 64-bit, mat

I'm new to openCV. I'm editing an image and need to read and write contiguous pixels over large rectangular patches of the image, but not the whole image.  My input images are single channel grey scale, with CV_16UC1 as input and CV_8UC1 as output. I'm currently accessing pixels using MatConstIterator_.

```
Mat image, image_read = imread(infilename, 0);
image_read.convertTo(image, CV_16UC1);
//...define img_dim_y, img_dim_x
Mat imout(img_dim_y, img_dim_x, CV_8UC1);

MatConstIterator_<uint16_t> pin = imageIn.begin<uint16_t>(), pixel_in_end = imageIn.end<uint16_t>();
MatIterator_<uint8_t> pixel_out = imageOut.begin<uint8_t>();
for(; /*selected pixel in a patch*/; ++pixel_out , ++pixel_out)
        *pixel_out = My_transform(*pixel_in);
```

This is memory bandwidth limited, and spends all its time reading and writing pixels, at a rate of 10 micro seconds per pixel. My machine is pretty modern so this is much slower than the ~MHz ram clock. For a 64 bit machine, it ought to be possible to read in 4 16-bit pixels at once, and write out 8 8-bit pixels at once, using a few shift operations. This would speed up the pipeline by at least 4-5x. How do I coax that data in and out of a openCV Mat?

Comment: What's the implementation of `My_transform`? You may be able to rewrite that to take advantage of existing vectorized operations that OpenCV supports. Otherwise you roll up your sleeves and work the the underlying buffer directly and vectorize it by hand (with SSE or AVX).

Comment: It's not likely that memory bandwidth is a limit here. It's a linear scan, the reads are likely to come from L1 cache most of the time. You're just working on to small chunks of data one at a time (and there's probably some overhead in the iterators, but i never measured that).

Comment: The transform is under development and is not well defined yet.

Comment: OK, well then you first need to finish defining the transform algorithm, because that's where bulk of the work lies. Until then, the only meaningful thing you could do is rewrite that loop to use [`cv::Mat::forEach`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) which will take advantage of all the CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something like this. The following will read in pixels 4 at a time, but it segfaults in random places after a fraction of the image is read.

```
//For a Mat img formatted as a CV_16UC1
uint8_t* alignas(64) Data = (uint8_t*)img.data;
for(int i = 0; /*selected pixel in a patch*/; i += 8){
    uint16_t p0, p1, p2, p3; //pixels
    uint64_t word = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(Data)[i];
    p0 =  (word & 0x00000000000000FF)        + ((word & 0x000000000000FF00) >> 8);
    p1 = ((word & 0x0000000000FF0000) >> 16) + ((word & 0x00000000FF000000) >> 24);
    p2 = ((word & 0x000000FF00000000) >> 32) + ((word & 0x0000FF0000000000) >> 40);
    p3 = ((word & 0x00FF000000000000) >> 48) + ((word & 0xFF00000000000000) >> 56);
    //do things with pixels
}
```